# Trying to Understand my Data: New to Statistics

Tags: categorical-data, continuous-data

I’m new to statistics and I’m a bit overwhelmed by all of the methods that I’ve been reading about. I’m finding that my biggest hurdle is understanding how my data would fit into different models.

I have computational quantum chemistry data. I am attempting to correlate adsorption energy to adsorbent size. There are seven adsorbents of similar chemistry.

A lot of my reading has led me to ANOVA but I’m not sure that my data would fit this type of a test. I’m honestly not sure if it would fit any test. Any help in understanding this would be helpful.

I believe that the energy values qualify as continuous data and the size would qualify as categorical

Comment: Start by plotting your data, which will later help you understand what statistical inferences, descriptions, or predictions would answer your research question. This can include histograms, scatterplots, boxplots, SVD projection plots, and others. Also compute descriptive statistics about the data. Also consider what existing models there might be between adsorption energy and adsorbent size.

Comment: [This web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/) is a succinct explanation of what types of tests are typically appropriate for which types of data.

Comment: If you are new to statistics, I would personally learn the Bayesian approach first :) Here's a wonderful resource with free YT lectures: https://xcelab.net/rm/statistical-rethinking/ And here's the first 2 chapters of the book https://xcelab.net/rmpubs/sr2/statisticalrethinking2_chapters1and2.pdf